# Differentiate notes in eledpar columns

Tags: footnotes, eledpar

I am trying to use `eledpar` with a `\Columns` environment. I have two parts of text and they contain notes. Is there a possibility to print the line number for the right side notes with and R as the line numbers?
So far I was trying the macro:

```
\let\oldBfootfmt\Bfootfmt

\renewcommand{\Bfootfmt}[3]{%

\let\printlines\printlinesR

\oldBfootfmt{#1}{#2}{#3}}
```

but this is adding the R to all notes.

Is there a way to add this only for the Rightside?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt,twoside,openwright,makeidx,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts]{eledpar}
\usepackage[french,polutonikogreek,english,italian,german,latin]{babel}


\footparagraph{B}
\addtolength{\skip\Bfootins}{1.5mm} 
\nonbreakableafternumber[B] 
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Columns
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\linenummargin{left}
\beginnumbering
\begin{center}
\pstart
$\alpha{}$
\vspace{1cm}
\pend
\end{center}
\pstart
\noindent
\edtext{Lorem ipsum}{\lemma{left Lorem}\Bfootnote{lorem ipsum footnote on the left column}} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
\pend
\pstart
Mauris non metus urna. Nam id est sit amet odio fermentum tempus. 
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumberingR
\begin{center}
\pstart
$\beta{}$
\vspace{1cm}
\pend
\end{center}
\pstart
\noindent
\edtext{Lorem ipsum}{\lemma{right lorem}\Bfootnote{lorem ipsum footnote on the right column}} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
\pend
\pstart
Mauris non metus urna. Nam id est sit amet odio fermentum tempus. 
\pend
\endnumberingR
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\end{document}
```

It creates two footnotes one for the right colum linked to line 2 and one to right column that should display 2R. but is still a simple 2.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you supplement the code with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I have added a MWE.

Comment: I will look on this proble, tonight. But just an advice : don't use any vspace directly in pstart, but use optional argumenet of pstart. And you should migrate to reledmac / reledpar.

Comment: sorry, not tonight, but I hope tomorrw. C

Comment: Cf https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/433

Comment: also do not manipulate \Bfootins directly, but use \Xbeforenotes (in reledmac, I don't remember name in eledmac, but as you will have to migrate to reledmac ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version 2.5.0 of reledmac provides two new hooks to add line flag in note:

- \Xlineflag for critical footnotes
- \Xendlineflag for critical endnotes

You could use them as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt,twoside,openwright,makeidx,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts]{reledpar}
\usepackage[french,polutonikogreek,english,italian,german,latin]{babel}
\Xlineflag
\Xendlineflag

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Columns
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\linenummargin{left}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\noindent
\edtext{Lorem ipsum}{\lemma{left Lorem}\Bendnote{Left}\Bfootnote{lorem ipsum footnote on the left column}} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
\pend
\pstart
Mauris non metus urna. Nam id est sit amet odio fermentum tempus. 
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\noindent
\edtext{Lorem ipsum}{\lemma{right lorem}\Bendnote{Right}\Bfootnote{lorem ipsum footnote on the right column}} dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
\pend
\pstart
Mauris non metus urna. Nam id est sit amet odio fermentum tempus. 
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\doendnotes{B}
\end{document}
```

The version have been sent to CTAN on 2015/11/13.

Comment: I have managed to install it as the issue433.tex is compiled properly. Now I need to change my file and to convert it to reledmac.. thank you!

Comment: your welcome. Don't forget to validate the answer and up it. I will publish in CTAN not next week, but next next Week.